# nav tag with float:left

Tags: html, css

When I tried to float the `nav li` to the left, it goes after the header tag.

When I remove that left float, it comes under the header flag.

I think when I use `float:left`, it should be only on the left side of the header, but not after the header...

Kindly help me out.....

---

#### My code :

```css
.site-header{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
}

.site-nav ul {
    display : block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class = "site-header">
    <h1>this is title 1</h1>
    <nav class = "site-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**a clearfix**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to achieve the desired effect :

```css
.site-header {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
}

.site-header:before, .site-header:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.site-header:after {
    clear: both;
}

.site-nav ul {
    display : block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class = "site-header">
    <h1>this is title 1</h1>
    <nav class = "site-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The float pulls the element out of the natural document flow.  You can try a clearfix on the containing element, just add the class clearfix (as in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfzu86hr/2/):

```css
.site-header{
 border-bottom: 5px solid #999;
}

.site-nav ul {
 display : block;
 float: left;
}

/* Begin Fix float container issues */
.clearfix:after {content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix       {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix    {height: 1%;}
.clearfix           {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

```html
<header class="site-header clearfix">
    <h1>this is title 1</h1>
    <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```